# Array.find not working in Angular app; does work in Console

Tags: arrays, angular, find

An Angular app I'm developing has a `SourceService` that first fetches sources from an API endpoint, stores them into memory and serves as a local cache that can be retrieved by `id`. So far so good, I'd think. But the function `findSourceById` always returns `undefined`. Why?

```
  findSourceById(id: number): Source {
    console.log(this.sources);
    console.log(id);
    console.log(this.sources.find(s => s.id === id));
    return this.sources.find(s => s.id === id)
  }
```

Output of the above:

> Array [{id: 1} {id: 2}] // mockup
>
> 2
>
> undefined

However, if I use DevTools to assign the array to a new global variable and then run the same `find` function on that variable, it does return the expected element.

Also, if I insert the `debugger` statement just before the return statement, I see that `this.sources` is still an Array of two, but that the `s` in the `find` function definition is undefined. It looks like JavaScript is incorrectly passing the Array elements into the loop iteration.

Comment: Can you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.sources));` as well please? Is it possible that the elements are being added to your array *after* `findSourceById` has run?

Comment: The only reason that you are getting undefine is that when you are trying to find something in the array, the array is empty i.e its length is zero.

Comment: stringify result: `[{"id":1,"title":"Bruksanvisning Foamglass","author":"Joe McMutton","file":"obscured","offset":10},{"id":2,"title":"enkel sida","author":"jag","file":"obscured","offset":1}]`

Comment: added some findings after using debugger (see last paragraph).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem was the `===` operator and the fact that, *somehow*, the `id` passed in the function was of the type string. Strange, because Angular did not complain about receiving a string while expecting a number (as per the type hint).

Answer (score 1):

Do you try another way like using filter instead of find?

```
return this.sources.filter(s => s.id === id)
```

Comment: It could be a comment.

Comment: this returns an empty Array

Answer (score 0):

it happens when find can't find any matched item in array returns undefined and causes a problem, you can handle it and say if you couldn't find any matched item return a message or something else for e.g:

```
findSourceById(id: number):Source | string{
    console.log(this.sources);
    console.log(id);
    console.log(this.sources.find(s => s.id === id));
    return typeof this.sources.find(s => s.id === id) !== 'undefined' ? this.sources.find(s => s.id === id) : 'element not found'  
  }
}
```

working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2vxgfp)

Comment: That's good error handling, but the problem is that **sources** has value {id: 2}  but find method, return undefined !!!

Comment: @Arash no it can't be if it finds the id won't return undefined.

Comment: look at 3 consoles and their outputs in question.

Comment: @Arash yes :-) you are right, so there is a problem in array!!! check my demo, if array is correct this won't happen.

Comment: Yup, you have handled undefined return very well ;-)

Comment: Have a look at this post. [View injection container for angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454764/view-injection-container-for-angular/51747958#51747958) Please share you'r views. :)

Comment: this does not address my problem, though

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue in pure Javascript (not Typescript).

As @bluppfisk mentioned above, the issue with `.find` was the strange transformation to the `string` type.

I solved it with adding `.toString()`:

```
    const mergedSources = sources.map((source) => ({
        ...source,
        ...sourcesFromDB.find(
            (sourceFromDB) => sourceFromDB._id.toString() === source._id.toString(),
        ),
    }));
```

Comment: I wonder if the reason is that the console does not support typescript and the Angular/TS code you write is converted to standard JS where different rules apply and where certain types get converted.

Comment: @bluppfisk You are right. Sorry, I forgot to note it's plain Node's JavaScript, not Angular.